# Laptop backlight is out when starting the computer

Tags: windows-7

When I turn on my computer, the backlight is off. This has occurred every time I've turned the computer on since installing Windows 7 less than a year ago. If I hibernate the computer and bring it back, the backlight comes back on. External monitors work fine.

I haven't seen this issue with any other machine. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: What kind of machine and/or monitor is this (I'm guessing a laptop)?  What version of Windows 7?  What's the video card?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making sure that you have the latest BIOS. You can download this from the manufacturers website. Is the back light literally completely off or is it just very dim? Maybe the brightness is set to the lowest setting but that's generally still obviously on.